# A huge apt log file from failed upgrade - what went wrong & how do I fix it?

Tags: 12.04, apt, upgrade, logging

When attempting to upgrade from the 12.04 to a newer LTS it seemed to hang for ages (a good day or two) on "preparing for upgrade" and then the whole system started to suffer. Eventually I rebooted and found that starting was not going to happen due to the HDD being full. It turned out that the upgrade folder had a file called apt.log which was 166GB in size.

I removed it which fixed the not booting problem.

Clearly this is *something* not working correctly but more importantly (from my perspective): How can I make sure that this does not happen again and, therefore, actually upgrade.

**Update**

One of the side effects of this failure was aptd ate all my CPU: [Help: “aptd” is maxing out my CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589840/help-aptd-is-maxing-out-my-cpu) I have that under control now but I still do not know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there might have been too many kernels in `/boot` solving this problem (as documented in my answer here: [how do I "rebuild" or "repair" APTD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598525/how-do-i-rebuild-or-repair-aptd/607971#607971)) appears to have gotten to the bottom of things.