# how do I "rebuild" or "repair" APTD?

Tags: apt, upgrade

#### How do I "rebuild" or "repair" aptd?

I don't mean up the various utilities to rebuild and reconfigure which has not solved my problem suggesting that something more fundamental is damaged. I am looking for a totally fresh and clean replace/rebuild with all old cache etc cleaned out as not knowing what I need to fix I am hoping this more aggressive approach will simply wash away the fault.

If aptd came on a disk as int he old days I would uninstall and reinstall at this stage. As it is (as far as I know) *the* process for doing that I don't know what to do.

#### Background

The problem I am trying to solve with this question may have been triggered during the upgrade process itself.

[A huge apt log file from failed upgrade - what went wrong & how do I fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589504/a-huge-apt-log-file-from-failed-upgrade-what-went-wrong-how-do-i-fix-it)

I figured out how to shut down aptd and apt-get and get my CPU back but this does not address the underlying problem that aptd is actually damaged. I think if I can do this that the problem will be addressed.

[Help: “aptd” is maxing out my CPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/589840/help-aptd-is-maxing-out-my-cpu)

I should point out that the most complicated thing I compiled and ran a make file for was no more complex than "hello world". I may need baby steps.

Comment: Hey Matthew, for a bit of clarity can you tell me, how broken is your package management ? Mostly can you still install packages, try it, sudo apt-get install "something here" and let me know, also here is the manual for the aptdeamon, might be worth a read https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+package/aptdaemon

Comment: Ps What Ubuntu version 12.04 14.04 or 14.10 etc

Comment: 12.04 is the version of Ubuntu I am using.

Comment: It would appear that I may have found the problem - too many kernels in /boot. I am now running a huge update that seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (that I needed) appeared to be that maybe aptd was fine but the /boot area was a bit too full - fixing this was the "repair" that was needed. I discovered this quite by accident while browsing related questions (and their related questions).

However what I originally thought was that APTD was corrupted and needed to be purged and rebuilt. It's a whole other debate as to if this is even an answer to the wider question that I asked.

### What I did

Removed the old config files which, according to an answer here ([My /boot partition hit 100% and now I can't upgrade. Can't remove old kernels to make room](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171209/my-boot-partition-hit-100-and-now-i-cant-upgrade-cant-remove-old-kernels-to)) is safe to do.

I also tried `sudo dpkg -r linux-image-2.*` which just seemed to be recursive and broken in some way that was beyond me. Killed it with control+C.

Switched to synaptic package manager and uninstalled a few older kernels. Then tried to get the out of date packages to update. It has been awhile since apt-get has been able to do anything so I felt this was something that needed to be done ASAP.

This had the effect of locking up synaptic and I had to terminate it it with `killall -9`.

Then a comment on my question about this ([Is it safe to remove old vmlinuz.* files from /boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607652/is-it-safe-to-remove-old-vmlinuz-files-from-boot)) led me to [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) and this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge $(dpkg -l 'linux-image-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d')
```

This cleaned up just shy of 3MB of disk space.

I then ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` which started the upgrade of 1260 packages. Needing about a Gig of archives.

Then I waited.

The next day I came back to it to see that it was waiting for me to respond to a prompt regarding gnome config. I chose the default option.

That completed successfully. I then did a clean, update and clean (because I am a newbi) and did `sudo apt-get upgrade` again and installed 3 more upgrades.

TL;DR: I think I needed to remove old kernels... that seemed to work.